# Move data of some Apps to SD card

Tags: rooting, sd-card, app2sd

I have Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime (4.4.4 and rooted) ... I have some dictionaries Apps... I installed the main App.. when we want to use.. we should download dictionaries package for each language we want... I tried to move the folder to SD Card ... it's ok!! But the files dont belong more to App so it doesnt recognize them (as if one should download them again).. if we move back the folder to internal memory... it's ok again.... is there a method?!!

Comment: Have you checked with our [app2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info), which explains the principles and names the multiple approaches available – such as Data2SD, Link2SD, or DirectoryBind?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) could help you. It allows you to move apps to SD and link them so the system "thinks" they are still on your device's internal storage. I would give a try.

Comment: Could you include a method? One line answers are not really helpful :)